# Is there a way to request a certain location of a text file to be read in C++?

Tags: c++, file, text, fstream

I'm using a text file which is in two lines. Each line has several thousand numbers on it (signed doubles). So it would look like this:

```
X.11   X.12   X.13   ...
X.21   X.22   X.23   ...
```

For each loop of my program I want to read one number from each line. So for the first iteration of the loop it would be `X.11` & `X.21` and for the second iteration `X.12` & `X.22` and so on. I don't need to store the values.

the expected output:

```
X.11  X.21
X.12  X.22
X.13  X.23
```

How can this be done in C++?
I usually read files using `fstream`, and reading the file line-by-line with `std::getline(file, line)`. How would I read one number from each line?

Comment: X.11 & X.12 should be X.11 & X.21??

Comment: You could do what you want but it might be easier to write a program to transpose the file in its entirety and then read it line-by-line.

Comment: Are your numbers length and line length fixed? In this case you could calculate where the next column starts and use [seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) (Asking cause the example looks like it...)

Comment: Just sayin': preprocessing this file in binary form could be useful (fixed offsets)

Comment: *"For each loop of my program I want to read one number from each line."* but you are trying to read `X.11` and `X.12` in your first iteration? Aren't these two numbers contained in the same line? Could you please add some pseudo code or so to clarify what you really try to achieve? This looks like you are just trying to read the first two numbers of each line which would be kinda simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I assume you need:** *I want to read one number from each line.*
>   otherwise comment me; I will delete the answer.

Read the **file** with 2 streams in parallel:

```
std::ifstream input_file_stream_1( "file" );
std::ifstream input_file_stream_2( "file" );

std::string line_1;
std::string line_2;
std::string ignore;
std::getline( input_file_stream_2, ignore );    // ignore the whole first line

for( ; input_file_stream_1 >> line_1 && input_file_stream_2 >> line_2; ){
    std::cout << line_1 << " and " << line_2 << '\n';
}

input_file_stream_1.close();
input_file_stream_2.close();
```

**the input:**

```
X.11   X.12   X.13   ...
X.21   X.22   X.23   ...
```

**the output:**

```
X.11 and X.21
X.12 and X.22
X.13 and X.23
... and ...
```

how it works?
Since your file only has 2 lines, so I used two `input_stream` over the same file. One of them for the first line and the other for the second line. But before going to for-loop. the `input_file_stream_2` reads the first line and no need to use that since the `input_file_stream_1` wants to read this. So after ignore that line ( first line ). The `input_file_stream_1` has line 1 and `input_file_stream_2` has line 2. Now you have two lines with to streams. And in the for loop, ( or while ) you can extract each text by `>>` operator

---

**or with `std::regex` library:**

```
std::ifstream input_file_stream( "file" );

std::string line_1;
std::string line_2;
std::getline( input_file_stream, line_1 );
std::getline( input_file_stream, line_2 );

std::regex regex( R"(\s+)" );
std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::iterator > begin_1( line_1.begin(), line_1.end(), regex, -1 ), end_1;
std::regex_token_iterator< std::string::iterator > begin_2( line_2.begin(), line_2.end(), regex, -1 ), end_2;

while( begin_1 != end_1 && begin_2 != end_2 ){
    std::cout << *begin_1++ << " and " << *begin_2++ << '\n';
}

input_file_stream.close();
```

**the output:(as the same above)**

```
X.11 and X.21
X.12 and X.22
X.13 and X.23
... and ...
```

---

NOTE:
There is more than one way to this

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain that for loop in the first method. How does it work without an iterator?

Comment: @Hadi Yes. I will do it

Answer (score 2):

> I don't need to store the values.

Sure, but if you did, say in two arrays of doubles, then your loop would be trivial, and much faster than regular disk reads. And two arrays of several thousand doubles is probably less memory usage than you think it is. 1 Mb of RAM can contain 131072 eight byte doubles.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already read the line using `std::getline(file, line)`, you can take the string you got, and tokenize it `char* p = strtok (yourline, " ");` and then *p would result X.11 in the first line, and for the next one you just call `strtok` again

Answer (score 1):

For an fstream you can use `tellg` and `seekg` to store and restore the position in the stream. However, I haven't verified that they work well together with formatted input.

Assuming you don't want to store the result in memory and it is only two lines another solution would be to open the file twice - and treat it as if you were reading the lines from two different files.